# How can I get colored url within head titles in ConTeXt?

Tags: context

I am currently working on a ConTeXt cheat sheet. Each command is designed as a link to the wiki. Most, but not all of the subsubjects are dedicated to one command. I would like to stick to this semantics, but I cannot get URL colored inside titles. And I would like them to appear obviously as URLs.

Here is what I did so far:

```
\setupinteraction[state=start]
\def\Commande#1{%
   \goto{\tex{#1}}%
   [url(https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/#1)]%
}
\starttext
\startsubject[title={Mise en page}]
\startsubsubject[title={\Commande{setuplayout}}]
\Commande{setuplayout} %just to check it works outside title
\stopsubsubject
\startsubsubject[title={Un exemple}]
\stopsubsubject
\stopsubject
\stoptext
```

EDIT : of course, I can solve this with a dirty trick, changing my macro this way

```
\def\Commande#1{%
   \goto{{\color[blue]{\bf {\tex{#1}}}}}%
   [url(https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/#1)]%
}
```

to emulate url decoration, but this is not what should be done.

Comment: For me I get working links in title and in text. What do you think is not working?

Comment: @TeXnician. My head. I first wanted to post about activating colour, then I thought "…mmm and what if it is not a color issue but a link issue". So I checked on ConTeXt live, forgetting to add `setupinteraction=yes`. When I realized it, I was so confused I sticked with my error. Updating my post to the color issue. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, okay. I do not get colors as well, so I wondered whether this was your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConTeXt resets the `style` and `color` value for interactive elements in section titles.

To get the color for your link back in the title you have to pass the `\setupinteraction` command as argument to the `commandbefore` key of `\setuphead`.

```
\setupinteraction
  [state=start]

\define[1]\Commande
  {\goto{\tex{#1}}[url(https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/#1)]}

\setuphead
  [commandbefore={\setupinteraction[color=interactioncolor]}]

\starttext

\startsubsubject[title={\Commande{setuplayout}}]
\Commande{setuplayout}
\stopsubsubject

\stoptext
```

[image]